# mysql query - contains?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, full-text-search, mysql-error-1064

how can i search for a particular string in mysql?
I tried using contains- gives me error:

```
SELECT r.name
     , r.network
     , r.namestring
     , i.name
     , r.rid
     , i.id
     , d.dtime
     , d.ifInOctets
     , d.description
FROM router AS r
INNER JOIN interface AS i ON r.rid = i.rid
INNER JOIN 1278993600_1_60 AS d ON i.id = d.id
                               AND d.dtime BETWEEN 1279027200 AND 1279029000
     WHERE r.network = "ITPN"
       AND i.status = "active"
       AND i.description CONTAINS ' DBK'
```

Please help.

Comment: CONTAINS is Full Text Search (FTS) syntax, and the key word is supported on both SQL Server and Oracle (though different supporting syntaxt).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
AND i.description LIKE '% DBK%'
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking for `LIKE`:

```
AND i.description LIKE '% DBK%'
```

**More Info:**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html
- http://www.htmlite.com/mysql011.php

Answer (score 1):

use like, i.e. AND i.description LIKE '%DBK%'

Comment: Note there should be a leading space before `DBK`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
...AND i.description like '% DBK%'
```

Or

```
...AND upper(i.description) like '% DBK%'
```

If you want to get anything with `DBK`, `DbK`, `dbk`, `dBk`, ...

Comment: From my experiences, 'LIKE' is not case sensitive by default, so there is no need for 'UPPER()'.

Comment: @pferate: It varies. Oracle's `LIKE` is case-sensitive. I couldn't remember at the time I wrote, but MySQL's is case- *in* sensitive by default (just looked it up).

Comment: It depends on the collation, the -ci collations are case insensitive (used by default), the -cs ones are case sensitive